# Using my own Login Page to authenticate with Azure AD using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, model-view-controller, azure-active-directory

**What I want:** I want to use my own login page to try authenticate to Azure AD to ensure that they have Access, then there after check if they exist in the DB(AspNetUsers Table). This would mean that they need to be registered to use the app if they exist in Azure AD(which will be synced to an on-premise AD).

**What I have found:** It seems that this is not possible and that it will always redirect to the `azure login screen`(If I can call it this) and once authenticated, it will redirect back to the web application and sign in. Is this true, or is there a way to do it the way I want to ? I know its possible if the web app is within the same network and working with the on-premise AD.

In the past I have used Azure ADB2C using the following code, but have no idea how I can use my own login screen, and at the time I also could'nt find anything that allowed me to use my own login screen to pass details such as a username and password to Azure AD for authentication:

```
public void SignUpSignIn(string type)
        {
            //Logout();
            TempData["SignInOutType"] = type;
            // Use the default policy to process the sign up / sign in flow
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge();
                    return;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                } 
            }

            Response.Redirect("/");

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**EDIT**

I just noticed that if you use Azure AD Premium 1 or 2, then you can create a custom sign-in page. Has anyone used this and how far can you customize it ? I saw a video of ADB2C where you can apparently specify your page, the css and fields and then the signin page will look just like your page - Has anyone used this before ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to not try to skip the MS login page.
There is a way to do it, but it will not work for users with MFA, or come from on-prem AD etc.

If you want to define a subset of users with access to the app,
I suggest you find your app from under Enterprise applications in the Azure AD management blade in Azure Portal.
From there you go to Properties and set User assignment required? to Yes.
Now you can assign users from the Users and groups tab.

Another way is to add a validation step to after a user authenticates, check against your DB at that time and fail the authentication if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have read the same about the MS Login Page, but my client has specified a specific look and I would have liked to try my best to keep to that. Hmm, I am a little disappointed that MS has not allowed something like this. I will then just have to do 2 logins(One for AAD and the other for the web app), or just let AAD be the only login. At least if the client isnt happy, I can safely say it is for security reasons. Thanks for your help nevertheless

Comment: I just read something now about customizing your sign-in page from the Azure portal(AD Directory) - I updated my post, Please check it out and let me know if you have had any experience with this ?

Comment: That's the branding feature that allows you to change some of the images and text on your organization's login page. It's limited but allows you to change the background and logo for example.

Comment: I have marked your answer as the accepted answer as everything you have said is exactly as my research has found. It doesnt seem like there is anything else that can be done - Thanks for trying to assist.